# python selenium : move_to_element() not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying mouse hover action on a visible element and then click on a hidden sub-menu item. `move_to_element()` does not seem to be working with ChromeDriver. However, there are no exceptions on running the code, just the action isn't happening.

I have also tried `sleep()` between actions and `webDriverWait` which shows timeout on running the code.
I am using chrome 56.0 with python 2.7 and selenium 3.0.2.

Following is the HTML code

```
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="about-us.html" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
 About
 <i class="caret"></i>
 </a>   

<li>
<a href="about.html">Introduction</a>
</li>
```

---

Following is part of my test case

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


   mainmenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("path_to_about_element")
   submenu =driver.find_element_by_xpath("path_to_introduction_element")
   action=ActionChains(driver)
   action.move_to_element(mainmenu)        
   action.move_to_element(submenu)        
   action.click().perform()
```

Comment: Could you share those `"path_to_about_element"` and `"path_to_introduction_element"`?

Comment: path_to_about_element= "/html/body/header/nav/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a" and path_to_introduction_element = "/html/body/header/nav/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a"

Comment: Could you use `mainmenu = driver.find_element_by_link_text("About")` and `submenu =driver.find_element_by_link_text("Introduction")` instead? Even if it doesn't solve your issue I suggest you to avoid using absolute `XPath` to locate elements

Comment: Thanks for responding :). As suggested, I tried using link text but got following exception on hidden element `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Introduction"}`

Comment: Also, using relative `xpath` for both elements didn't help but no exception this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys. I finally figured out that `moveToElement()` doesn't work if physical cursor is inside the browser window. It is a known issue with ChromeDriver.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=605

Answer (score 6):

Try below code and let me know the result:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

mainmenu = driver.find_element_by_link_text("About")
action=ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(mainmenu).perform()
submenu = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Introduction")))
submenu.click()
```

This should perform mouse hovering over `mainmenu` element and wait until `submenu` element presence and clickability

Comment: This is giving `TimeoutException`

Comment: Do you actually saw that `Introduction` element appeared on page while script execution? could you try `len(driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Introduction"))`? There might be some hidden links with same name in `DOM`...

Comment: can see just a flash even with `time.sleep(10)` and `len()` returned 0.

Answer (score 3):

This may work:-

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('myelementid').scrollIntoView();")
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar issue and solved it by using `move_to_element_with_offset()` instead of `move_to_element()`.  Change the `move_to_element(myElement)` call into:

`move_to_element_with_offset(myElement, 0, 0)  # 0, 0 specifies no offset`

Answer (score 1):

I also just realized, that there is a difference between:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, 0, 0).perform()
```

and

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', element)
```

The former resulted in an exception telling me that the move target was out of bound.

The latter seems to be more relieable and also faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and let me know if still face the same issue :

```
mainmenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("path_to_about_element")
submenu =driver.find_element_by_xpath("path_to_introduction_element")
action=ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(mainmenu).move_to_element(submenu).click().build().perform()
```

Comment: seems my version of selenium doesnt support `build()`. Getting following exception `AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'build'`